# HTML div not coming to top of `embed` object - IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I have the following HTML

```
<embed class='pdf_container'  src='welcome.pdf' style ='width:100%;height:500px;' ></embed>

<div id="show_message"  class='message_wrapper' >

 <div id="message_content"> The requested operation ...  </div>

</div>
```

and in CSS

```
.message_wrapper{
   position:fixed;
   z-index:1000;
   height:100px;
   width:100%;
   background:red;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
.pdf_container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:100;
}
```

Actually i want to show the `#show_message` over the `.pdf_container` and it works well in Firefox but not in `IE` , it ignoring the `z-index`.

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Thank you.

See Screenshots:

**IN IE**

[IN IE 8,9](http://i49.tinypic.com/1twiyv.png)

**and in FF**

[IN FIREFOX](http://i50.tinypic.com/2luouh4.png)

Comment: its working fine in ie as well...which ie ur talking about

Comment: please specify IE version

Comment: unfortunately its not working in any version of IE (or atleast IE8,9)

Comment: @SachinRawal No , the message is showing under the `PDF`.

Comment: please add snapshot i am not able to reproduce this one

Comment: @SachinRawal added screenshot.

Comment: dont knw what happeing pdf is not showing in my browser ( i have use my own pdf )

Comment: got it let me check now

Answer (score -1):

You will need to set WMODE to Transparent inside the embed tag.

```
<embed class='pdf_container'  src='welcome.pdf' style ='width:100%;height:500px;' wmode="transparent" ></embed>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this you surly get solution as i did and its working fine in my local system :-) cheerss
Little diffrent form your code but i am sure you will get it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fRsUv/

```
html { height:100% }

#container {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

#pdf {
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

#layer_over_pdf {
    width:200px;
    z-index:2;
}

#pdf, #layer_over_pdf {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}



<div id="container">
 <div id="pdf"><embed id="pdfEmbed" src="JavaScript_DHTML_Mat_V4.pdf" style="width:500px; height:600px" type="application/pdf"></embed></div> 
 <div id="layer_over_pdf">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working on IE, PDF is showing top of the page.